# Get errors when trying to generate Haddock documentation using build-and-serve-docs

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, nix-shell, documentation

On Windows 10 with WSL2 (Ubuntu)

I go to `plutus-apps`,
then run `nix-shell`,
there after I run `build-and-serve-docs` from within nix-shell

See image for errors..

After build I can access a documentation link but there's no haddock documentation.

I did have a space issue yesterday that prevented some file from being written, is there maybe a way to "clear cache" and rebuild docs ..

*Is there maybe another way I can build the haddock docs, or can I access the docs elsewhere?*

[image: build-and-serve-docs]

[image: hosted-docs-missing-haddock]ck.imgur.com/Rkonl.png

Comment: Are you on the right revision for week 1? You can check with git rev-parse HEAD. It should be 4114...5c8a

Comment: Yes thanks - checked that - am on commit 41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a

Comment: This sounds like corruption due to running out of disk space to me. Can you run `nix-collect-garbage -d`, re-enter the nix-shell and run that command again?

Answer (score 1):

Bro, it happened to me just now.

It was because I was in the wrong directory
you have to call this from the **plutus-apps** root directory:

You said you are already at this directory but could you please double check?

This is correct:

> [nix-shell:/mnt/c/me/Dev/plutus/**plutus-apps**]$ build-and-serve-docs

Incorrect:

> [nix-shell:/mnt/c/me/Dev/**plutus**]$ build-and-serve-docs